# Angular 2 click on later placed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, semantic-ui

My page is basically split in two parts:

```
<div *ngIf="initState">
  <div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     {{ someText }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" (click)="notInitialAnymore();">Click</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!initState">
  <div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Another title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     {{ someOtherText }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The point is that the accordion in initalState works fine, but the one in not initial state not - no reaction on a click on that element. In my case it is easy to make a work-around, but how should I do it without a work-around? How can I make the second accordion call:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how is the first accordian is opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hidden] attribute, when you use *ngIf the element is not created in the dom so jQuery can not init the accordion on it.

```
<div [hidden]="!initState">
  <div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     {{ someText }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" (click)="notInitialAnymore();">Click</button>
</div>
<div [hidden]="initState">
  <div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Another title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
     {{ someOtherText }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```